# MYSQL deletion failed through JDBC and return error response

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just have below code base, and it works fine manually. But throws exception when I used it in jdbc driver.

**Code:**

```
String query = "DELETE
                FROM tests
                WHERE e2e_product_id =410 AND
                      test_name = 'PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1' AND
                      test_id <> 
                    (SELECT MAX_TEST_ID FROM (SELECT MAX(test_id) MAX_TEST_ID
                     FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id =410
                     GROUP BY test_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) TEMP)"
```

**Exception:**

> java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)

Any leads?

Comment: Isnt exception clear in itself: "Subquery returns more than 1 row" ??

Comment: Did you try to run subquery separately. What result it produces?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(test_id) MAX_TEST_ID FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id =410 GROUP BY test_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` - this subquery returns more than one row

Comment: How to resolve this ?

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan It depends on what your intended logic is.  One immediate fix would be to use `WHERE test_id NOT IN (...)`.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan Please mention output of inner query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your data or exact logic, but I can suggest using `WHERE NOT IN` logic with the subquery instead of `<>`:

```
DELETE
FROM tests
WHERE
    e2e_product_id = 410 AND
    test_name = 'PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1' AND
    test_id NOT IN (
        SELECT MAX_TEST_ID
        FROM (
            SELECT MAX(test_id) MAX_TEST_ID
            FROM tests
            WHERE e2e_product_id = 410
            GROUP BY test_name
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) t
    );
```

This would get around the subquery returning more than one result error.  In general, your subquery would return one max value for each test.  So, assuming your logic is that you don't want the `test_id` matching *any* group, the above logic should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since error definitely shows us that returned row count is multiple, you should change `test_id <>`  into `test_id not in` and put following part into paranthesis.